# Intel's C++ compiler for Windows

Tags: c++, intel

It supposedly integrates with Visual Studio, but does it come with it's own C++ standard library? Or does it use the one provided by VC++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least the last time I checked, it used the one that came with VC++. I believe you *can* buy the Dinkumware library for it separately, if you really want to (but Dinkumware supplies Microsoft's library, so you're getting a different version of the same, not something radically different).